# WordPress SQL commands in textareas

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, prepared-statement

Let's say I have a form that generates the following on post:

```
$title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']);
$text = esc_textarea($_POST['$text']);
```

then I use prepare statements to insert the values in the database but I have a question. I have this line to send the values to the database:

```
$wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_emails VALUES('', %s, %s)", $title, $text);
```

is this safe lets say to prevent people from inserting something like `SELECT * FROM table_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prepared statement 'injects' values and wraps your query in 'tags' and stuff. I'm not a MySQL expert as I rely on query builders these days but the general purpose of a prepared statement is to avoid injection.

The above should output something like

```
INSERT INTO `$table_emails` VALUES ('','title', 'text');
```

If someone tried to inject an statement into the above I'm pretty sure (not used wordpress in about 6 years) it would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `$table_emails` VALUES ('', '\';SELECT * FROM blah;\'', '');
```

Notice the injection is now but a string my young padawan.

But yea, prepared statements are a boss man's way of preventing bobby drop tables from getting in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sourRaspberri =) so, is this safe? i already made a test and the sql is inserted as a simple string. no harm done.

Comment: yea you'll be alright, one thing to consider though is html and javascript injection. Not sure if wordpress covers this but check that when displaying your data (wherever the inserted data is displayed on your site) use `htmlentites()` this will result in a string opposed to html on your page! http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: for what i've read in the wordpress codex both sanitize_text_field() and sanitize_textarea_field() take care of that. (just have to change the esc_textarea() to sanitize_textarea_field() ) anyway, thanks =)

Comment: that's alright! You should defo look into laravel though ;) it's soooo good :D